# Unable to use ILogger instance provided via DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, azure-functions

Essentially, there are two different ways I get ILogger instances. One works perfectly fine, the other doesn't.

I have an Azure Function like this:

```
class AzureFunctionClass {

     private readonly ISomeClass _someclass;

     public AzureFunctionClass(ISomeClass someClass){
          _someclass = someClass;
     }

     public Task<IActionResult> AzureFunction(ILogger log){
             log.LogInformation("This works, I see this message when run");
             _someclass.ExecuteMethod();
     }
}
```

Another class, not containing Azure functions, like this:

```
class SomeClass : ISomeClass {

     private readonly ILogger<SomeClass> _log;

     public SomeClass(ILogger log){
           _log = log;
     }

     public void ExecuteMethod(){
           _log.LogInformation("This doesn't crash so _log isn't null, but it 
                                doesn't write anything");
     }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
class Startup : IWebJobsStartup {

     public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder){
          builder.Services.AddScoped<ISomeClass, SomeClass>();
          builder.Services.AddTransient(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));
          builder.Services.AddScoped<ILogger<SomeClass>, Logger<SomeClass>>();
     }
}
```

And no, I'm afraid that AzureFunctionClass cannot just pass its ILogger instance to ISomeClass as a parameter.
I've also looked everywhere for log files, such as in Azure Storage Explorer, to see if it's possibly just not writing to the Azure Portal console. Every log file I found had logs for the working case described above, and none of them had logs for the other case.

Answer (score 0):

Current syntax shown has some issues with this injected dependencies.

```
class SomeClass : ISomeClass {
    private readonly ILogger _log;

    public SomeClass(ILogger<SomeClass> log) {
        _log = log;
    }

    public void ExecuteMethod() {
        _log.LogInformation("This doesn't crash so _log isn't null, but it doesn't write anything");
    }
}
```

Second issue is that logging is added by default and your manually added settings are overriding the default setup.

```
class Startup : FunctionsStartup {

    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder) {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AzureFunctionClass>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISomeClass, SomeClass>();

        //...
     }
}
```

Technically all you needed to add was your function class and its dependencies.

Reference [Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#registering-services)

Comment: Hmm, made those changes and I'm afraid there's still not logging in SomeClass.

Answer (score 0):

At present, the function runtime has a bug due to which **it filters out** any log that is created with a category that doesn't start with string `Function.`.

See these GitHub issues:

- [#4425 - ILogger is not injected when using new DI functionality](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4425)
- [#4345 - Remove filters for ILoggers created by customer DI](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4345)

The logger injected in the function method is done by the function runtime which creates the logger with category set to `Function.<FunctionName>.User`. So this gets logged properly. But the logger that is injected into the constructor is done by the asp.net core DI framework, which sets the category name for the logger as `Type.FullName` (type in your example case is `SomeClass`). Because it's fullname doesn't start with `Function`, the lines logged with this category are filtered out.

There are two ways to workaround this.

**Option 1: Change host.json to not filter logs from your namespace**

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "logLevel": {
      "<YourNameSpace>": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**Option 2: Inject ILoggerFactory in your ctor, and create a logger with a category that won't get filtered**

```
class SomeClass : ISomeClass {

     private readonly ILogger _log;

     public SomeClass(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){  // Note that we inject ILoggerFactory
           this._log = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(
            LogCategories.CreateFunctionUserCategory(this.GetType().FullName));  // Must use CreateFunctionUserCategory to create the log category name otherwise the log gets filtered out.
     }

     public void ExecuteMethod(){
           _log.LogInformation("This should get logged correctly.");
     }
}
```

Note that, ILogger is already registered into DI framework by the function runtime (as mentioned in NKosi's answer), so those lines can be removed.